# Copy all files excluding one file in shell script

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting.

I have a command which copies all `tml/xml` files in the current directly to another as below:

```
cp -f *.[tx]ml $path
```

But I need to exclude one file (excludeme.xml) while executing the above command.
I tried the below command but did not work.

```
find . -name "excludeme.xml" | xargs -0 -I {} cp -f *.[tx]ml $path
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
find . ! -name excludeme.xml | ...
```

or

```
ls *.[tx]ml | while read -r file; do 
    test x"$file" = xexcludeme.xml || cp -f "$file" "$path"
done
```

Note the leading 'x'; it is probably not necessary in modern shells, but will
prevent errors when the file name begins with '-'.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned that I have more votes than btmorex.  The grep -v | xargs solution is cleaner.  I don't want to delete this because it is a good technique, but I like the grep -v solution better.  On the other hand, it would omit files with names like "foo-excludeme.xml", so perhaps it is not so good.

Comment: Thank you. It works.

But is there some how we could edit the original command 

find . -name "excludeme.xml" | xargs -0 -I {} cp -f *.[tx]ml $path

and get this working?

Comment: The above command using find does not throw any warning or error, but still copies exclude.xml

Comment: @WilliamPursell: +1. but [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: You can try: find . ! -name excludeme.xml

Comment: find . ! -name excludeme.xml did not work.

I was just curious what was wrong in the above using find. If this does not work, I will use the one suggested by you.

Thanks!

Comment: `find -name '*.[tx]ml' ! -name exclude.xml -exec cp {} $path \;` worked fine for me

Answer (score 2):

If this is `bash` then

```
shopt -s extglob
cp !(excludeme).[tx]ml destination
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *.[tx]ml | grep -v excludeme.xml | xargs cp -f -t $path
```